# How to avoid use of rm -rf in bash scripts?

Tags: shell-script, rm

I had once a dangerous experience with the use of `rm -rf`, due to a unset variable.
Since then, I have been extremely cautious in composing a script that involves `rm -rf`. Cross checking the spell mistakes, spaces etc. multiple times.

So far, I have been following these practices wherever possible:

- Using non-root user.
- Avoid using of `*`, and using more specific file paths.
- Avoidig use of variables for directory name.

So I would like to know if there is some standard/recommended practices or approach or a script to use `rm -rf`, especially with `*` so that it won't be destructive if there is a some manual mistake in script.

**Update:**

A work in progress bash utility to empty a given directory is created here at: https://github.com/g1patnaik/system_utilities/tree/dev/empty_directory

Comment: See also [What's the fastest way to remove all files & subfolders in a directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/277214)

Comment: You might want to read http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/ -- I don't agree with all the advice there but it's a good starting point to prevent errors like unset variables.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks, the article is quite useful. Though it doesn't have a direct answer for the solution I am looking for, the suggestions I can take into account.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this question is about avoiding `rm -rf`, but about avoiding ending up in states where the operation is unsafe or using it in ways that could have uncertain consequences.  When it comes to spelling errors, you could catch some of them using tools like [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and setting certain shell variables (e.g. `failglob` in `bash`, and `nounset` for example). Still, ultimately it comes down to forming a habit of reading your code before you run it and testing it on throwaway or backed-up data.

I don't see the use of complicating it too much.  If you want to delete all the directory contents, it would be the most straightforward approach to delete the directory entirely and recreate it.

```bsh
rm -rf -- "$directory" && mkdir -p -- "$directory" || exit
```

Note the quoting of `$directory`.  It is needed because the string in `$directory` would otherwise be split into terms so that if the variable's value is `foo bar`, the code would remove the two names `foo` and `bar`. The words would additionally be expanded as file name globbing patterns, making it dangerous to remove a directory called literally  `*`.  We use the `--` to end option parsing before the actual directory name, enabling us to work with directories called, e.g., `-f` or `--version`.

The `exit` above would be executed if either `rm` or `mkdir` failed.  The code would naturally also reset any ownership and other metadata on the directory it recreates.

Another approach would be using `find`.

```bsh
find "$directory/." ! -name . -delete
```

The above uses the `-delete` predicate of `find`, which is non-standard but commonly implemented.  It deletes everything beneath the given directory except for the directory itself.  In this case, the original directory entry is left in place rather than recreated.

Using portable `find`, we would write this

```bsh
find "$directory/." -depth ! -name . -exec rm -rf {} +
```

---

Note that your code would execute `cd -` even if your first `cd` failed, possibly leaving your script in an unexpected working directory. Your code also fails in removing hidden names and it would fail with "argument list too long" if the globbing pattern expands to too many names. If `*` does not match anything, it will terminate a script running with the `failglob` (or equivalent) shell option set (note that this is a good thing if the directory was expected to be non-empty, but was empty).

Comment: Recreating it means some metadata (ownership, permissions, ACLs, other extended attributes, birth time...) will be lost though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's not clear whether this is an issue or not. Re-reading the question, it's not clear what restrictions are at all.

Comment: @they Thanks for the suggestiosn. Actually, the above code I created only while writing the question and not verified. Fortunately, I havenot used in any of my scripts. I have been avoiding variables at all in the rm scripts.

Comment: @they Besides, I think it will be highly useful if there is such util that can empty a given directory with only a single argument that is the directory itself and fails with multiple arguments (i..e, parsing error due to unquoted variables). I will start writing one in github.

Comment: @GP92 At some point, you will have to start trusting the caller and say, "Hey, _you_ messed up here, not me".

Comment: @GP92 In my previous comment, "start trusting" should really be replaced by "move responsibility over to".

Comment: A work in progress script is created here at: https://github.com/g1patnaik/system_utilities/tree/dev/empty_directory

Comment: @GP92 Sorry, but apart from using `getopt` in a way that makes it incompatible with the `getopt` on non-GNU systems, your code contains unquoted variables, and you appear to parse pathnames from strings which means you disqualify working with directories containing specific characters. Your code is too sprawling for me to attempt to trust it enough to test run it (given that it's a script that removes files). I don't believe in babysitting users. I believe in teaching them how to use the system correctly from the start, which also means making mistakes.

Comment: @they I understand. I will try to make improvements. Just sharing so that if someone could contribute. :)

Comment: In addition to losing metadata, removing the directory itself will make your life "miserable" if you are already in that directory.  The `find`s look nice though.

Comment: Update:  I ended up using a slight variation on the find.  `find "$directory/." -depth ! -name . -exec echo rm -rf {} \;`.   `echo` "comments" out the `rf` which prints line by line what it would delete, so I make sure it's safe first.  When it's ok, remove the `echo` leaving the `rf` live.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most common protection against an empty variable with regard to `rm -rf` is ensuring the variable in not empty.

```
if [ -n "$directory" ]; then
   rm -rf "$directory"
fi
```

When you are appending to a base path this is an important check to make to ensure you don't end up passing only the base path, thus deleting far more than intended. Consider this example:

```
rm -rf "/home/user/$Dir"
```

If the variable `$Dir` is empty, the command will be `rm -rf /home/user/`.

If you know more about what you are deleting, you could also check to ensure the path is a file, `-f`, or a directory, `-d`.

See `man test` for most info on test expressions.

Quoting protects against spaces in the path name splitting it into 2 arguments.

Comment: What protection does `-n` offer, exactly, against the scenario of an unset or null value of `directory`?  On my system, the command `rm -rf` by itself does nothing, and returns a successful result code. Sure, quoting is essential, but I don't see that `-n` is helpful.  I suspect you meant to suggest the use of `-d`, such as: `if [ -d "$directory" ]; then` ...

Comment: @JimL., if you have something like `rm -rf ~/"$directory"` it becomes much, much more important to check that the variable isn't empty. (with `directory` unset or null, the command would be more like `rm -rf ""`, but that's also silently ignored.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Granted, but that's not the example in this answer.  As posted, the test for `[ -n "$directory" ]` in this example is of no use whatsoever, that I can see.

Comment: I was working in the context of the question and focusing only on a partial path and protecting against an unset variable.  I can add more detail to the answer, but don't forget to check out the man page mentioned.

Comment: `test -n "$directory"`  will be false if `$directory` is unset or set to an empty string.  That's literally what it does.  It'll also accept a file instead of a directory, or a name of a file that doesn't exist.  Either way it prevents an `rm -rf $directory/` from resolving to an `rm -rf /`  You probably want an else with an error message though.

Answer (score 2):

It's also a good idea to find alternative patterns where you don't end up needing `rm -rf`, or where it's somewhere safe.

One example might be making extensive use of `mktemp` with paths stored to local variables of functions so everything can just clean up after itself.  If you aren't ingesting whole trees of unknown files into your process you might never need it.

If you are ingesting trees you can probably make sure there's a fixed prefix on your working path so you never wipe out `/` even if a variable is accidentally zero.